# How to access Firebase protected realtime Database with authenticated user in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I'm using Firebase Sign with Email and getting authToken and Firebase UID
Able to access public database but I want to access protected database with authenticated user.
Firebase Real Time Database Rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit read access to authenticated users, you could leverage this in your rules like `auth != null`. The rule you provided could limit that the authorized user's can write and read the Data.

However, we generally recommend limiting write access further.

For example, your app may want to make sure users can only read and write their own data. In this scenario, you would want a match between the auth.uid variable and the user ID on the requested data:

```
{
     "rules": {
       "users": {
            "$userId": {
         
            ".write": "$userId=== auth.uid",
             ".read": "$userId=== auth.uid"
                       }
                  }
              }
 }
```